# Clean up Javascript/Nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coding-style

I'm new to javascript / nodejs and I'm working on some code by trying to clean it up.

I'm using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) nodejs library to deal with making the asynchronous parts of the code easier.

Right now the code looks like this:

```
Object.prototype.method = function(){
  var self = this; 
  // bunch of code
  async.forEach(self.someArr, function(someObj, callback){
    self.somefunc(someObj.someProp, function(err, aNewObj) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      self.someOtherArr.push(aNewObj.someOtherProp);
      callback();
   });
 }, callback);
}
```

However, i'd like to replace the anonymous function with another named function also defined on the object's prototype. Because of the way the code is structured, I don't know how I could create a new function to pass into `async.forEach` while preserving the proper `self` value.

What I want it to look like:

```
AnObject.prototype.method = function(){
  var self = this; 
  // bunch of code 
  async.forEach(self.someArr, self._newMethod, callback);
}

AnObject.prototype._newMethod = function(someObj, callback){
  var self = this;
  self.somefunc(someObj.someProp, function(err, aNewObj) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    self.someOtherArr.push(aNewObj.someOtherProp);
    callback();
  });
}
```

But that obviously doesn't work because of the context change.

Comment: If the named function also uses variable `self` internally, it shouldn't make a difference. The only time something might go funny is if it's using `this`.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear. The named function also uses self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless that function is defined in the same closure where self exists, you'll need to use something to proxy to it:

```
async.forEach(self.someArr, function(someObj, callback){
   self.somefunc(someObj.someProp, function(err, aNewObj) {
       self.otherfunc(err, aNewObj, callback);
   });
 }, callback);
```

Comment: It's all about closure inception with js.

Answer (score 1):

You could make this work easily enough if you change your style a bit.

```
AnObject = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.method = function(){
        // bunch of code 
        async.forEach(self.someArr, self._newMethod, callback);
    };

    self._newMethod = function(someObj, callback){
        self.somefunc(someObj.someProp, function(err, aNewObj) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            self.someOtherArr.push(aNewObj.someOtherProp);
            callback();
        });
    };
};
```